# Cannot setListAdapter in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android development so as programming. I learnt the example of creating list view and another example of creating tabbed layout using MyFragmentPagerAdapter. But when I try to merge these two together (that is to make a list view inside different fragment of tabs. The "(this, generateData())"  in fragment class will get red lines saying it cannot be applied. Also the "setListAdapter" will get red lines saying the method cannot be resolved.

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment  {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
        return view;
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

        //2. setListAdapter
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<DrugItem> generateData(){
        ArrayList<DrugItem> items = new ArrayList<DrugItem>();
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 1","First Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 2","Second Item on the list"));
        items.add(new DrugItem("Item 3","Third Item on the list"));
        return items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setListAdapter()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setListAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29) is a method of `ListFragment`, not `Fragment`. Make your class extends `ListFragment` instead and you should be fine.